# Pandas group by x, sort by y, select z, aggregating in case of multiple maximum values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Suppose I have a dataframe `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group_id' : [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3],
                   'amount'  : [2,4,5,1,2,3,5,5,5],
                   'x':[2,5,8,3,6,9,3,1,0]})

   group_id  amount  x
0         1       2  2
1         1       4  5
2         1       5  8
3         2       1  3
4         2       2  6
5         3       3  9
6         3       5  3
7         3       5  1
8         3       5  0
```

I want to group it by `group_id`, then pick `x`, corresponding to the largest `amount`. The part which I cannot figure out is how to deal with cases when there are multiple rows with maximum `amount`. For example, 3 last rows in the df above.
In such cases, I would like to aggregate values of `x` using mean, median or mode of x. I am trying to get the solution, in which I can implement every one of these 3 aggregation methods.

I saw many questions here, which solve the problem without dealing with multiple maximum values. For example, I could do something like this:

`df.sort_values('amount', ascending=False).groupby('group_id').first().x`

But I do not know how to implement different aggregation approaches.

EDIT: The second part of this question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73227675/pandas-group-by-x-sort-by-y-select-z-aggregating-in-case-of-multiple-maximum).

Comment: Kindly add your expected output dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you question right, you can use custom function with `GroupBy.apply`:

```py
out = df.groupby("group_id").apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series(
        {
            "mean": (d := x.loc[x["amount"] == x["amount"].max(), "x"]).mean(),
            "median": d.median(),
            "mode": d.mode()[0],
        }
    )
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
              mean  median  mode
group_id                        
1         8.000000     8.0   8.0
2         6.000000     6.0   6.0
3         1.333333     1.0   0.0
```

---

Or `.describe()`:

```py
out = df.groupby("group_id").apply(
    lambda x: x.loc[x["amount"] == x["amount"].max(), "x"].describe()
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
x         count      mean       std  min  25%  50%  75%  max
group_id                                                    
1           1.0  8.000000       NaN  8.0  8.0  8.0  8.0  8.0
2           1.0  6.000000       NaN  6.0  6.0  6.0  6.0  6.0
3           3.0  1.333333  1.527525  0.0  0.5  1.0  2.0  3.0
```

Comment: Thanks! This answers my question for one column ```x```. How to do it for multiple columns? Suppose I have columns ```x1```, ```x2```  up to ```x100``` and I want to find median value for them, corresponding to the highest ```amount```, sorted by ```group_id```. So the desired output is a dataframe with columns ```median_x1```, ```median_x2```, ... ```median_x100```. Of course, I can simply copypaste the code to have 100 lines like ```"x_89": d["x_89"].median(),```, but I am wondering whether there is more neat solution.

Comment: @MoyseyAbramowitz It's better to open a new question here on StackOverflow (describe the proble + sample input/expected output). I'd try to look at it.

Comment: Thanks! I have added the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73227675/pandas-group-by-x-sort-by-y-select-z-aggregating-in-case-of-multiple-maximum.