# Pandas group by x, sort by y, select z, aggregating in case of multiple maximum values, multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

This is the second part of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73214933/pandas-group-by-x-sort-by-y-select-z-aggregating-in-case-of-multiple-maximum).

Suppose I have a dataframe `df` and I want to select `x1` and `x100`, corresponding to the largest `amount`, grouped by `group_id`. If there are multiple rows with the largest `amount`, then I want to select medians of `x1` and `x100`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group_id' : [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3],
                   'amount'  : [2,4,5,1,2,3,5,5,5],
                   'x1':[2,5,8,3,6,9,3,1,0],
                  'x100':[1,2,3,4,8,9,9,4,5]})

   group_id  amount  x1  x100
0         1       2   2     1
1         1       4   5     2
2         1       5   8     3
3         2       1   3     4
4         2       2   6     8
5         3       3   9     9
6         3       5   3     9
7         3       5   1     4
8         3       5   0     5
```

So the desired output looks like this:

```
          median_x1  median_x100
group_id                        
1               8.0          3.0
2               6.0          8.0
3               1.0          5.0
```

For only 2 columns (`x1` and `x100`), I can simply add 1 line to @AndrejKesely solution to the previous question, something like this:

```
out = df.groupby("group_id").apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series(
        {"median_x1": (d := x.loc[x["amount"] == x["amount"].max()])['x1'].median(),
         "median_x100": d["x100"].median()}
    )
)
```

How to do this in a neat way, which will work for 100 columns, i.e., `x1`, `x2` up to `x100`? Ideally, I do not want to copypaste one line 100 times and manually changing name of a column in an editor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
df.groupby('group_id').apply(
    lambda x: x[x['amount'] == x['amount'].max()
               ].drop(columns=['amount', 'group_id']).median())
```

You can also use names of columns instead of .drop():

```
df.groupby('group_id').apply(
    lambda x: x.loc[x['amount'] == x['amount'].max(), ['x1', 'x100']].median())
```